Using proper conjunctions
Can you explain the difference between if and while to me? That's what I mean

If you are reading now I won't bother you- as I was told it is a correct sentence meaning if you are really reading now because I'm not certain I won't bother you.

While you are reading now I won't bother you- to me it is also correct. Just here we are certain that reading is really the case. Still, some people told that this example doesn't work with "now". Why? Is that even true?



Please show some effort at research. What time clause? Do you mean the adverb now?

Like what? I presented my issue  and please answer because I can't find information about that on the net.

Like the meaning of those two words and sample sentence.  https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/while

if= provided that while= during the time

You say the difference between if and time clauses. Whereas your sentences have if versus while and the adverb now. And also, there is no time conjunction.

I have changed that

If you are reading now, I won't bother you.
You have just discovered that the person is busy reading, so you decide not to try to talk to them just now.
While you are reading I won't bother you.
You know that the person is reading and will wait until they have finished. As Barmar says, now is unnecessary and it would be more natural to say it the other way round - I won't bother you while you are reading.

I think this would be best "I won't bother you now while/when you are reading" 1) I used "when" in my example. Would you accpet it? I know it might be less natural but "when" has two meaning and could mean the same as "while"

Yes, that would be acceptable too.

"if" is usually used when referring to something happening at a specific time, now in your example sentence.
On the other hand, "while" tends to be used when referring to a continuous period of time. So you might say

I won't bother you while you're reading.

which means you won't bother them during the entire period of time when they're reading. You wouldn't say now with while.
